# scp using ssh-ident confuses filename with hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm trying to send a file to a remote system:

```
@ravi@svelte:~$ scp /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf ravi@tara:
All keys already loaded
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf: Name or service not known
@ravi@svelte:~[255]$ ls -l /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5,558 Feb 19 20:06 /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf
@ravi@svelte:~$
```

Why is `scp` thinking that the first argument is a hostname, rather than a filename?

I'm running `OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016`.

Comment: What is `scp` in your system? It looks like some alias or `bash` function. What does `type scp` return? Do you have something in you `ssh_config`?

Comment: Thanks, I had `~/bin/scp` as a symlink to [`/usr/bin/ssh-ident`](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident). I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident/issues/35) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem, that your `scp` is symlink to something that does not accept the syntax of `scp`.

As you already pointed out in the comments, the problem comes from [`ssh-ident`](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident). Not sure how did you install it or set it up, but it is most probably bug there.

Comment: ssh-ident is a python script which is designed to be symlinked to and behaves based on the name of the symlink. [Issue raised](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident/issues/35).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an incorrect syntax. From scp manual:

> ```
>  scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
> ```

You have to tell `scp` where you want to put the file after the semicolon, i.e:

```
@ravi@svelte:~$ scp /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf ravi@tara:/path_to_file
```

Comment: No: `scp /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf ravi@tara:/tmp/path_to_file` gives output: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf: Name or service not known`